How to define the network settings inside a ubuntu virtual machine inside VirtualBox?
On windows 10 I am running a VirtualBox with an Ubuntu OS inside, and I seem to have issues to set up the network inside. ip addr show shows the following output:

while the network settings is empty!
I do not understand what is going on. Why do I see network adaptors defined with ip addr show but the Network settings is empty? So how to permanently shange my network settings? And what are these docker0 and vethe984e16@if5 adaptors? Can I remove them? if so how?

Please don't post duplicates How to bridge a Ubuntu VM in VirtualBox to WiFi network adaptor on Windows 10?

I do not post duplicates. They are related questions but not the same

The are the same and stemming from the same lack of understanding about how networking works for the VM.

That is correct, I seem to have lacking understanding of how networking works in a VM. That is why I could ask thousand questions. Also, the setup now works for me, but I do not know how. To my understanding the setup should NOT work at all, but it does!!

In the question this one is a duplicate of I already explained in broad and very basic strokes how Virtualbox works in this regard. If it doesn't match your user case then please edit the other question to clarify what are your requirements.

I already did update the question. I want to have outside internet connection via the Windows WLAN internet adaptor.
I need to have connection to a USB-based ethernet adaptor Ethernet in the 192.168.200 subnet. Normally the VM would have a fixed static IP address like 192.168.200.100.

Is the WiFi accessing the internet in the host? Likely not because you're also using Ethernet. So, this is a moot point because, apparently, you want to control the WiFi from the VM and that's NOT possible. It's possible and easy with USB devices using the Virtualbox's USB passtrough feature but then that device is disconnected from the host and you WON'T be using the network settings but connecting the WiFi with the same drivers and using it the exact same way you would with a bare metal OS, NEVER trough the Virtualbox network settings.

The WIFI is accessing the internet/ Only the WIFI. The other ethernet is only connected to a local device lying on the table, not connected to the internet. That device is in the 192.168.200 subnet


I do not understand what is going on. Why do I see network adaptors defined with ip addr show but the Network settings is empty?

This is what's going on:

ip addr only deals with the "live" state, so it pulls information directly from the kernel. The 'Settings' app, meanwhile, relies on the NetworkManager service so that it could persistently store the configuration (for NM to apply every time the interfaces are detected), and everything it shows is obtained indirectly through NetworkManager.
It could be that NetworkManager is not running at all; or that it has been configured to ignore the Ethernet interfaces for some reason. Run nmcli dev to check whether they are listed at all and whether they're shown as "unmanaged".

i.e. that they are actually defined in the file like /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml

They aren't, unless you have manually defined them there. The whole purpose of that file, originally, is to tell Netplan to stay away from the interfaces and to let NetworkManager manage them.

And what are these docker0 and vethe984e16@if5 adaptors? Can I remove them? if so how?

docker0 is a 'bridge' interface (functionally like an Ethernet switch). As the name suggests, it is used by Docker to provide a virtual network for containers. It currently connects two ports: the host OS itself (Ubuntu) and the one veth that has master docker0 set.
veth* is a 'veth' interface – one end of a virtual Ethernet cable; the other end is inside a container that's currently running (usually both paired veths disappear with the container being stopped).
Both could be deleted using ip link del ..., but as mentioned, ip only deals with "live" state – it will not prevent Docker from re-creating the docker0 bridge on next startup, nor re-creating veths the next time it runs a container.

Oh I like this answer

Answer does not seem to explain how I actually change the settings, i.e. that they are actually defined in the file like /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml ...

Answer does not seem to explain how I actually change the settings The thing is: You don't, not for the way you think this will work anyway, because it doesn't. You need to understand how virtualization works and it's limitations, not post duplicate after duplicate as already commented.

@ChanganAuto: I feel like you didn't even read the post; you just saw the word "VirtualBox" and got fixated on it. The two questions in the post have nothing to do with virtualization; they're specifically Ubuntu questions, so please stop the "how virtualization works" thing here.
